# Spread sheet issue with sending from ipad to Gmail on computer

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

Ok, the last few days my coworker has been sending emails but the times aren't transfers to me but will transfer to my phone and outlook? What could be the cause? I am needing to get this resolved asap because this is a work related problem. We aren't the only one's in the company having this issue it is also our HR team and owner.